# My drink electrocuted me

Tags: food-safety

I combined acacia gum, apple cider vinegar, l-glutamic acid, egg white protein,  flaxseed oil, and blackberry / citrus selzer water in a closed container.... it electrocuted me when I tried to drink it! Why did this cooking reaction happen?

I researched hydrophilic and hydropholic reactions with seltzer water but I'm still confused.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why did this cooking reaction take place?

Comment: First of all, electrocuted means injured or killed with electricity. We're you actually injured or just surprised? Secondly, even if you had made a chemical cocktail that could operate as a battery, drinking it wouldn't create a circuit that could shock you. Sounds to me like a fizzy, acidic drink that caught you off guard and kind of felt like a shock.

Comment: Maybe you were just charged by walking on a carpet (or wearing sweater) and when you touched glass the spark jumped. Happens all the time.

Comment: You should ask this in Chemistry SE

Comment: what was the container (material) ?

Comment: maybe this question was a post from the ghost